# vcs trigger rules TeamCity and Plastic SCM

Tags: triggers, teamcity, plasticscm

TeamCity 2017.1 (build 46533)

Plastic SCM version 5.4.16.814 Doobie Brothers - China Grove

I have configured an include Trigger rule in TeamCity triggers to include changes from a particular VCS root and a specific file path.

+:root=testbuild_VCSTestBuilds:Utilities/**

The rule should only trigger a build if it detects changes within the utilities folder and ignore any changes in any of the other folders.

Having set this rule once a change is made it is recognized as a pending change - but no build fires off.

Have I done something wrong or is there an issue between TeamCity and Plastic SCM

Comment: I would review if your agents are active or if there is any kind of issue to assign the build to the agent.

Comment: Hi - the build agents are active and if the job is run manually everything is fine - the trigger rule just seems to not pick up changes within the folder.  If I remove the rule and leave it monitoring the whole root then it will trigger automatically.  The reason for applying the rules is that the developers have 3 discreet projects on a single branch (inherited issues) - the trigger rules should enable me to be selective on which changes (as they are in separate folders within the repository) should trigger the build

Answer (score 0):

On the VCS Trigger dialog where you're setting the trigger rule, make sure you have the appropriate branches included in the branch filter.

Comment: The VCS Roots are monitored and the branch is the main branch